# Google Adsense / Gambling workaround

Tags: google, google-adsense

I've run a website since 2001 with betting sites adverts for most of that time and Google Adsense for many years as well.  Five or six years ago I was generating £100-£200 per month from Google, but this has fallen by over 90% subsequently - people don't click them, basically!  So the following isn't a disaster.

Anyway, on 18 April I got an email giving me 72 hours to remove all betting adverts and betting related content or Google Adsense would be disabled from the site:

> VIOLATION(S) FOUND:
>
> GAMBLING: As stated in our program
>   policies, AdSense publishers are not
>   permitted to place Google ads on sites
>   with content related to gambling or
>   casinos. This policy includes driving
>   traffic to online gambling sites
>   through links or advertisements. More
>   information about this policy can be
>   found in our help center

Their 'review' of websites seems to be a direct result of the FBI action on 15 April, so advertising and content that I've had (and submitted to Google Search) is no longer acceptable after several years with no complaints.

**Does anyone have a constructive workaround that may satisfy Google without affecting my long-standing advertising policy?**

Comment: @John Conde - I'll amend the question to make it less subjective/argumentative.

Comment: ok. I'll reopen it now.

Comment: So your question is: _How can I break the TOS and not be punished for breaking the TOS?_ Seems like a really silly question to ask. A better question, and a more reasonable one, is _What alternative ad networks are there to AdSense for publishers of gambling content?_

Comment: My question asked why were Google happy for 10 years with the mix of advertisers I used - until I was suddenly given 72 hours to drop gambling adverts (its not a 'gambling content' site its a sports content site that occasionally has articles which quote the odds - much like the BBC does).

Comment: @Lèsemajesté thanks for trying to rephrase my question, but you clearly misunderstand the issue.  8 months after I asked the question your comment seems a bit arrogant to be honest, so perhaps you should think a bit harder before commenting on such an old question.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you could do to keep Google happy is remove your gambling adverts, there really aren't any shortcuts you can take unfortunately.